# PowerShell script for Azure Information Protection labeling

Tags: azure, powershell, office365, azure-powershell, uipath

I need to retrieve privacy labels of O365 files. I'm able to achieve that with this script:

```
$Status = (Get-AipFileStatus -Path 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\test.xlsx')
$ReportLine = [PSCustomObject]@{
         IsLabeled   = $Status.IsLabeled
         LabelId     = $Status.MainLabelId
     Label       = $Status.MainLabelName}


$Status.MainLabelId
```

Due to UiPath bugs, I need to target Powershell 64-bit. While I can achieve that, I'm facing an issue where I can't retrieve any output that I could use further in my RPA process. Could someone please suggest how I can fix this script and be able to get the output $Status.MainLabelId?

```
$powershell32 = $env:SystemRoot + '\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
& $powershell32 Get-AipFileStatus -Path 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\test.xlsx'
$ReportLine = [PSCustomObject]@{
         IsLabeled   = $Status.IsLabeled
         LabelId     = $Status.MainLabelId
     Label       = $Status.MainLabelName}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution.

```
$powershell32 = $env:SystemRoot + '\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' & $powershell32 Get-AipFileStatus -Path 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\test.xlsx' | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?